# Cómo comparo dos dataframes que tienen columnas con nombres iguales pero datos diferentes en R?

Tags: r

Cómo comparo dos dataframes que tienen columnas con nombres iguales pero datos diferentes en R?

Cuáles serían los mejores métodos estadísticos y cómo lo haría en R?

***Supongo que la pregunta técnica sería cómo saber si los dataframes provienen de la misma población?***

Quisiera la respuesta para tres casos:

Caso 1:  Dataframes que tienen solamente variables numéricas.

Caso 2: Dataframes que tienen solamente variables categóricas.

Caso 3: Dataframes que tienen variables numéricas Y categóricas.

Lo que a mi se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

Aunque quiero comparar los 2 dataframes, comenzaría analizando las columnas que tienen igual nombre.

a) Para las variables numéricas que siguen la distribución Normal usaría

***Welch Two Sample t-test***

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Pongo este ejemplo en el que comparo dos distribuciones Normales.

```
t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), conf.int=TRUE)
```

b) Para las variables numéricas que NO siguen la distribución Normal usaría Wilcoxon rank sum test.

***Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction***

https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test

Pongo este ejemplo en el que comparo dos distribuciones NO normales.

```
wilcox.test(rpois(100, 100), rpois(100, 100), conf.int=TRUE)
```

C) Finalmente, para las variables categóricas, usaría Pearson's Chi-squared test.

***Pearson's Chi-squared test***

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test

En este ejemplo comparo dos columnas categóricas, generadas con las dos primeras letras del alfabeto.

```
chisq.test(table(sample(letters[1:2], 1000, replace = TRUE)),

           table(sample(letters[1:2], 1000, replace = TRUE)),

           correct=FALSE)
```